# Django admin site doesn't reflect the data from the form

Tags: django, admin

I want the user input data in my database so that the admin could have a list of users who have requested a leave.

The below are my scripts.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Leave(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    type_of_leave = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    from_date = models.DateField()
    to_date = models.DateField()
    reason = models.CharField(max_length= 180)
```

I'm not sure with this how to save the form from here to the database.
views.py

```
from .forms import LeaveRequestForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class LeaveRequestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'lrequests/request_form.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = LeaveRequestForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = LeaveRequestForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {
            'form':form
        }

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            employee_id = form.cleaned_data['employee_id']
            dept = form.cleaned_data['department']
            desg = form.cleaned_data['designation']
            rpt_mgr = form.cleaned_data['reporting_manager']
            tof = form.cleaned_data['department']
            from_date = form.cleaned_data['from_date']
            to_date = form.cleaned_data['to_date']
            reason = form.cleaned_data['reason']
            context.update({'name':name, 'employee_id':employee_id, 'dept':dept, 'desg':desg, 'rpt_mgr':rpt_mgr, 'tof':tof, 'from_date':from_date, 'to_date':to_date, 'reason':reason})
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

the below are the fields I wanted in my form.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Leave

CHOICES = (('1','Earned Leave'),('2','Casual Leave'),('3','Sick Leave'),('4','Paid Leave'))

class LeaveRequestForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    employee_id = forms.CharField(max_length = 20)
    department = forms.CharField(label = 'Department ', required = True)
    designation = forms.CharField(label = 'Designation ', required = True)
    reporting_manager = forms.CharField(max_length = 20, required = True)
    type_of_leave = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, required = True)
    from_date = forms.DateField(required = True)
    to_date = forms.DateField(required = True)
    reason = forms.CharField( required = True, max_length= 180)

    class Meta:
        model = Leave
        fields = ('name',)
```

I have even registered the model in the admin too

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from . import models

admin.site.register(models.Leave)
```

Comment: does it reflected in your DB?

Comment: The model does reflect in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your views.py function as -

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = LeaveRequestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            leave = form.save(commit = False)
            leave.user = request.user
            form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the form is a model form and register it in the admin. if it's still not showing up, then  there are probably some required fields that needs to be filled in which are not currently filled in which is preventing the form from saving to the DB

Comment: please check my updated question with code and help me.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a form, but you didn't tell Django to use it in the admin for that model. You need to define a ModelAdmin class and set its [`form` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin):

```
class LeaveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LeaveRequestForm

admin.site.register(models.Leave, LeaveAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the admin.py look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

@admin.register(models.Leave)
class LeaveAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [ 'name', 'department', etc...]
```

Comment: that's a mere customization to the viewing type in the database, how to i write a view so that my data get's stored in db.